# Ignore self signed ssl certificate in strophe js with https request

Tags: ssl, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I use Strophe library to connect to an OpenFire XMPP server. I am using the http-bind url as https://localhost:7443/http-bind/ for connecting to openfire server.

Openfire provided default self-signed certificates.

How to ignore the self signed certificate in strophe connection ?

Answer (score 1):

In the browser, JavaScript can not override the decision to trust a certificate. Only the user can do that manually. To do that, visit the http-bind URL directly and add an exception.